# Disable gmaps4rails 's feature of searching for "gmaps4rails.css"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I want the gmaps4rails gem to not search for "gmaps4rails.css".
To do so, I have to somehow pass enable_css = false.

The relevant file is this :
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails_helper.rb

Please help me out. I'm using Rails 3.0.7

Thanks a lot,
Michalis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Miscellaneous

```
 <%  enable_css = false
   enable_js  = false %>
 <%= gmaps( data_hash, enable_css, enable_js)          %>
 <%= gmaps4rails( markers_json, enable_css, enable_js) %>
```